Accessing files in Public Documents folder from ASP.NET Core app
I need to access a file in my Public Documents folder from my ASP.NET Core web application. However, I'm getting an exception.

Access to the path 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\USRAIL\EdiImporterWorkerService\Backups\BNSF - 2024.zip' is denied.

I was under the impression that the Public Documents folder would be accessible. Is that not the case? What is the easiest way to make it accessible?

What permissions does your c:\Users\Public folder currently have? Is it similar to https://i.sstatic.net/wjZG745Y.png? Do you have public folder sharing  enabled https://www.digitalcitizen.life/what-public-folder-how-use-it/?

@gunr2171: My permissions look exactly like that. I enabled sharing for the Public folder but still get the error. Note that I don't want to share it over the network. Rather, the web app needs to access the contents of this folder when it's running on the same machine.

@gunr2171: I had to add LOCAL SERVICE

The piece I was missing was giving access to LOCAL SERVICE.
Right click on Public folder, click Properties, click Advanced, click Add, add LOCAL SERVICE.
